# Where can I see the amount of "extra recursion" stack kept for recovery from recursion limit?

Tags: python, recursion, internals

This question is about trying to understand python internals.

Consider the code:

```
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(100)

def myfunc(n):
    print(n, sys.getrecursionlimit())
    try:
        myfunc(n+1)
    except Exception as e1:
        print('Cannot proceed')
        print(e1)
        try:
            myfunc(n+1)
        except Exception as e2:
            print('That went wrong')
            print(e2)

myfunc(0)
```

Warning - This code is meant for python internal research and causes python to crush. Leads to actual `Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.`.

This is the result:

```
....
....
92 100
93 100
94 100
95 100
Cannot proceed
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
95 100
96 100
97 100
98 100
99 100
100 100
101 100
102 100
103 100
104 100
105 100
106 100
107 100
108 100
109 100
110 100
111 100
112 100
113 100
114 100
115 100
116 100
117 100
118 100
119 100
120 100
121 100
122 100
123 100
124 100
125 100
126 100
127 100
128 100
129 100
130 100
131 100
132 100
133 100
134 100
135 100
136 100
137 100
138 100
139 100
140 100
141 100
142 100
143 100
144 100
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.

Current thread 0x0000379c (most recent call first):
  File "....test.py", line 7 in myfunc
  File "....test.py", line 9 in myfunc
....
....
```

This is what I imagine roughly going on:

1. The function counts up till close to 100 before hitting the recursion limit. Close to 100 and not 100 since some stack is used by python itself.
2. When the exception occurs the actual recursion limit is set higher to allow recovery.
3. Since my function insists on keep doing recursion it will hit the new limit after some time.
4. But this time this "extended limit" recovery mechanism is exhausted and a fatal stack overflow occurs.

Am I right?

My question: Can I see the amount of "extra recursion" stack in some system variable, using something equivalent to `sys.getrecursionlimit()`?

Comment: I think the reason you can go over 100, in this case, is because the second recurrance uses a a different startpoint. As far as I know, the stack overflow error is just a case of running out of memory - try it with more things running, or fewer, or on a higher-quality computer, and I would expect it to be different.